# How to efficiently get absolute value of a time interval in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, execution-plan, index-tuning, interval

I have a huge table in Postgresql-11 like following:

```
CREATE TABLE my_huge_table(
    tick_time timestamp(6) with time zone NOT NULL,
    brok_time timestamp(6) with time zone,
    trade_day date NOT NULL,

    --other fields ...
    ...

    CONSTRAINT my_huge_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tick_time)
);

CREATE INDEX idx_my_huge_table_td_time ON my_huge_table USING brin
    ( trade_day, abs(tick_time - brok_time) );
```

Then I make a query and want it to take advantage of the index `idx_my_huge_table_td_time`, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_huge_table
WHERE trade_day BETWEEN TO_DATE('20220104', 'YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE('20220104', 'YYYYMMDD') 
  AND ABS(tick_time - brok_time) < INTERVAL '10 s';
```

But PostgreSQL refuse to execute it, and said:

> ERROR:  function abs(interval) does not exist
>
> LINE 3:      AND ABS(tick_time - brok_time) < INTERVAL '10 s'
>
> ```
>            ^
> ```
>
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>
> SQL state:
> 42883 Character: 525

It looks like that the func `abs()` can **NOT** accept a interval value as a argument.

Then, I changed my query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_huge_table
WHERE trade_day BETWEEN TO_DATE('20220104', 'YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE('20220104', 'YYYYMMDD') 
  AND GREATEST(tick_time - brok_time, brok_time - tick_time) < INTERVAL '10 s';
```

This time it can be executed, but didn't take advantage of the index.

My questions:

1.How should I compose the expression of index? In fact I want it to record a distance(absolute interval value) between two timestamp fields;

2.How should I code the query that can use the index above?

3.In fact `GREATEST(tick_time - brok_time, brok_time - tick_time)` is **NOT** a good idea, since it invoked two times computing. Isn't it?

4.After created the index, I note that the real DDL SQL of the index reported by PostgreSQL is:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_my_huge_table_td_time ON public.my_huge_table USING brin
    (trade_day, abs(date_part('epoch'::text, tick_time - brok_time)));
```

Have the value of the expresstion casted into a `text` type? It apparently is **NOT** my expectation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to create a generated column as follows (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/G9Ayjc7z)):

I had an original answer (shown at end of answer), but I've revised it to use a [`Generated Column`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) (aka "Computed" or "Virtual" column) instead of an [`Expression Index`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) (aka "Functional Index").

This has the advantages of:

- a) It's calculated on insertion and does not have to be recomputed every time and
- b) it makes the SQL **much** clearer - see original answer below.

There's one disadvantage in that it uses more space, but I've found that this is not normally a critical issue (never seen it myself). Unfortunately, PostgreSQL does not yet have virtual generated columns - see link.

Your table definition should be as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE t 
(
  ticktime TIMESTAMPTZ, 
  broktime TIMESTAMPTZ,
  trade_day DATE,
  -- 
  -- other fields
  --
  abs_b_minus_t INTERVAL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (GREATEST(broktime, ticktime) - LEAST(broktime, ticktime)) STORED
);
```

Then create an index on `abs_b_minus_t`:

```
CREATE INDEX t_ix ON t 
USING BRIN (trade_day, abs_b_minus_t );
```

Populate:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES
('2022-02-14 14:43:55'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2022-02-14 12:43:55'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2022-02-14'::DATE),
('2022-03-14 14:43:55'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2022-02-14 12:43:55'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2022-03-14'::DATE),
('2022-02-14 14:43:55'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2022-05-14 12:43:55'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2022-02-14'::DATE);
```

Then we run:

```
SELECT 
  ticktime - broktime AS t_minus_b,
  abs_b_minus_t
FROM t;
```

Result:

```
t_minus_b             abs_b_minus_t
02:00:00                   02:00:00
28 days 02:00:00    28 days 02:00:00
-88 days -21:00:00  88 days 21:00:00
```

So, we see that it's working - we are obtaining absolute values of the difference between `broktime` and `tradtime`.

Now, we can check index usage - we run `SET enable_seqscan = OFF;` and then:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)
SELECT 
  broktime - ticktime
FROM t
WHERE abs_b_minus_t  < INTERVAL '30 DAYS';
```

Result:

```
QUERY PLAN
Bitmap Heap Scan on public.t  (cost=12.14..39.07 rows=423 width=16) (actual time=0.022..0.025 rows=2 loops=1)
  Output: (broktime - ticktime)
  Recheck Cond: (t.abs_b_minus_t < '30 days'::interval)
  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 1
  Heap Blocks: lossy=1
  Buffers: shared hit=3
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on t_ix  (cost=0.00..12.03 rows=1270 width=0) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=10 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (t.abs_b_minus_t < '30 days'::interval)
        Buffers: shared hit=2
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning Time: 0.042 ms
Execution Time: 0.052 ms
```

So, we are using `t_ix` with the BRIN index on our generated field.

### Original Answer:

```
CREATE TABLE t 
(
  ticktime TIMESTAMPTZ, 
  broktime TIMESTAMPTZ,
  trade_day DATE
  -- 
  -- other fields
  --
);
```

Now, we create our functional index as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX t_ix ON t 
USING BRIN (trade_day,  (GREATEST(broktime, ticktime) - LEAST(broktime, ticktime)));
```

Populate the table:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES
('2022-02-14 14:43:55'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2022-02-14 12:43:55'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2022-02-14'::DATE),
('2022-03-14 14:43:55'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2022-02-14 12:43:55'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2022-03-14'::DATE),
('2022-02-14 14:43:55'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2022-05-14 12:43:55'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2022-02-14'::DATE);
```

Now we test:

```
SELECT 
  ticktime - broktime AS t_minus_b,
  GREATEST(broktime, ticktime) - LEAST(broktime, ticktime) AS abs_b_minus_t
FROM t;
```

Result:

```
t_minus_b             abs_b_minus_t
02:00:00                   02:00:00
28 days 02:00:00    28 days 02:00:00
-88 days -21:00:00  88 days 21:00:00
```

So, we have the values and their absolutes.

```
SELECT 
  broktime - ticktime
FROM t
WHERE GREATEST(broktime, ticktime) - LEAST(broktime, ticktime) < INTERVAL '30 DAYS';
```

Result:

```
?column?
-02:00:00
-28 days -02:00:00
```

To check index usage, we disable seqscans:

Then, we run:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)
SELECT 
  broktime - ticktime
FROM t
WHERE GREATEST(broktime, ticktime) - LEAST(broktime, ticktime) < INTERVAL '30 DAYS';
```

Result:

```
QUERY PLAN
Bitmap Heap Scan on public.t  (cost=12.17..57.59 rows=567 width=16) (actual time=0.041..0.044 rows=2 loops=1)
  Output: (broktime - ticktime)
  Recheck Cond: ((GREATEST(t.broktime, t.ticktime) - LEAST(t.broktime, t.ticktime)) < '30 days'::interval)
  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 1
  Heap Blocks: lossy=1
  Buffers: shared hit=3
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on t_ix  (cost=0.00..12.03 rows=1700 width=0) (actual time=0.027..0.027 rows=10 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((GREATEST(t.broktime, t.ticktime) - LEAST(t.broktime, t.ticktime)) < '30 days'::interval)
        Buffers: shared hit=2
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning Time: 0.044 ms
Execution Time: 0.096 ms
```

So, we see that `t_ix` is used with the relatively efficient Bitmap

Comment: excellent!!

You have given me a very good starting point, from it I can compose a generated column more suitable to my work.
I can change the algorithm of the generated column to fit any requests in the future!

Thanks a lot! Good man!!!

Comment: @Leon - glad to be of help!